# Least ugly way to "methodize" the creation of Lists containing Objects from various classes

Tags: c#, list, oop, generics

I am a turbo newbie when it comes to programming, but I need to learn the ropes for a job.

I made a MyLists class reserved for creating and storing various Lists made out of various classes of objects, but I feel I'm going against the DRY principle, here's a snippet:

```
public class MyLists
{
   private List<Apple> ListedApples = new List<Apple>();
   private List<Orange> ListedOranges = new List<Orange>();
}
```

I made methods to enlist each:

```
public class MyLists
{
   public List<Apple> AppleLister(int howMany)
   {
      List<Apple> appleList = new List<Apple>();
      for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
      {
         Apple apple = new Apple();
         appleList.Add(apple);
      }
      ListedApples = appleList;
      return ListedApples;
   }
   
   public List<Orange> OrangeLister(int howMany)
   {
      List<Orange> orangeList = new List<Orange>();
      for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
      {
         Orange orange = new Orange();
         orangeList.Add(orange);
      }
      ListedOranges = orangeList;
      return ListedOranges;
   }
}
```

I felt it was too redundant and ugly, so I tried making a generics approach that could be invokable for whatever class is needed:

```
        public static void Lister<T>(List<T> list, int howMany) where T : class
        {
            new List<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object());
                list.Add(instance);
            }
            return List<T>();
        }
```

Naturally it didn't work, seems that mixing generic lists with objects is harder than mixing oil and water, I know there's a C# equivalent of a surfactant (change type maybe?), but after investigating around, the consensus is that such mixing should be generally avoided.

So my question now is, in what other way could one "methodize" a general enlister in this kind of scenario? The plan is to add objects which will be containing bits of info, namely location.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: `it didn't work` what does it mean? Having one class which returns different lists by calling different method is common. You call it factory.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I'm a fan of what you're doing but, in order to make it work, you should add a `new` constraint to your generic type parameter. That way, you will be able to invoke the parameterless constructor of type `T`:

```cs
public static void Lister<T>(List<T> list, int howMany) where T : class, new()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new T());
    }
}
```

I've also removed the superfluous parts of that code.

You might also streamline the implementation somewhat with some LINQ:

```cs
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, howMany).Select(n => new T()));
```

Note that, if you want to be able to create a new list inside that method if one doesn't already exist, you should declare the first parameter `ref`:

```cs
public static void Lister<T>(ref List<T> list, int howMany) where T : class, new()
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new T());
    }
}
```

Actually, it looks like your original type-specific methods don't take a list as input and always return a new one, so that would translate to a generic method like this:

```cs
public static List<T> Lister<T>(int howMany) where T : class, new()
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new T());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this proves I need to study more about Lists and maybe Lambda expressions, best regards.